# Responsive Design Questions for a Beginner

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm still a newbie when it comes to Responsive web design. I do have a some questions.

1. When creating Responsive Sites. Do i have to use twitter bootstrap/responsive frameworks? or is it a good practice if i create my own?
2. I want to make my first responsive menu, and i have seen several tutorials out there with different practices. which will you recommend?
3. Media Queries: ( PC, Tablet, Mobile ) Again, there are lot of tutorials out there... which will you recommend?

Answering these 3 questions will help a lot. I'm getting overwhelmed and confused because of the different practices in coding. Maybe asking Pro's like you will give me a heads up..

Comment: I can answer the first one: No.

Comment: 1 No, but you might find it useful; 2. & 3. Anything that elicits a response that is primarily an opinion s off-topic on [so]. Choose one, and see if it works. If it doesn't, try something different.

Comment: primarily opinion-based..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Twitter bootstrap can be a good start, but you might take more time to clean the file then actually work your responsive website.

2- Might be usefull : http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/responsive-web-tutorials/

3- Medias queries always come with resposive tutorials

Answer (score 1):

1. Twitter Bootstrap is NOT a must. There are a lot of responsive frameworks.
2. Recommendation of tutorial is not in scope of Stack Overflow.
3. *same as above*

Answer (score 1):

> When creating Responsive Sites. Do i have to use twitter bootstrap?

No there are many libraries available. like foundation, jQuery UI, YUI,EXT JS, KickStrap etc

> I want to make my first responsive menu, and i have seen several tutorials out there with different practices. which will you recommend?

Which is easily understandable for you.

> Media Queries: ( PC, Tablet, Mobile ) Again, there are lot of tutorials out there... which will you recommend?

Again best is the one which is easily understandable for you.